# Setting data- attribute in GWT / Bootstrap

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap, gwt-bootstrap

I am working with GWT and implementing bootstrap through GWT-Bootstrap library.

I can't seem to find a way to add data- attributes to my elements?

I can do it by writing HTML directly:

```
HTMLPanel htmlPanel = new HTMLPanel("<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn\" data-custom=\"some-custom-data\">Hello World</button>");
menuControl.add(htmlPanel);
```

But that's just ugly and defeat the purpose of using GWT (might as well write a plain HTML code).

I am looking for ways to do something like:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setText("Hello World");
button.setStyleName("btn");
// Fine up to here, but now i want:
button.setAttr("data-custom", "some-custom-data");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `button.getElement().setAttribute("data-custom","some-custom-data");` ?